# Add letter-spacing into sass settings of Foundation framework (6)?

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

```
$header-styles: (
  'small': (
    'h1': ('fs': 24, 'lh': $header-lineheight, 'mt': 0, 'mb': $header-margin-bottom),
    'h2': ('fs': 20, 'lh': $header-lineheight, 'mt': 0, 'mb': $header-margin-bottom),
    'h3': ('fs': 19, 'lh': $header-lineheight, 'mt': 0, 'mb': $header-margin-bottom),
    'h4': ('fs': 18, 'lh': $header-lineheight, 'mt': 0, 'mb': $header-margin-bottom),
    'h5': ('fs': 17, 'lh': $header-lineheight, 'mt': 0, 'mb': $header-margin-bottom),
    'h6': ('fs': 16, 'lh': $header-lineheight, 'mt': 0, 'mb': $header-margin-bottom)
  ),
  'medium': (
    'h1': ('fs': 48, 'lh': $header-lineheight, 'mt': 0, 'mb': $header-margin-bottom),
    'h2': ('fs': 40, 'lh': $header-lineheight, 'mt': 0, 'mb': $header-margin-bottom),
    'h3': ('fs': 31, 'lh': $header-lineheight, 'mt': 0, 'mb': $header-margin-bottom),
    'h4': ('fs': 25, 'lh': $header-lineheight, 'mt': 0, 'mb': $header-margin-bottom),
    'h5': ('fs': 20, 'lh': $header-lineheight, 'mt': 0, 'mb': $header-margin-bottom),
    'h6': ('fs': 16, 'lh': $header-lineheight, 'mt': 0, 'mb': $header-margin-bottom)
  ),
  ...
)
```

How can I add letter-spacing into my global style (`_settings.scss`)?

(that `$header-styles map` copy/paste bellow is defined into that `_base.scss` from the npm node modules of Foundation)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the original foundation loop to create the header styles like this :

```
// Adding letter spacing to Heading styles Foundation loop
@each $size, $headers in $header-styles {
  @include breakpoint($size) {
    @each $header, $header-defs in $headers {
      $letter-spacing-temp: 0rem; // setting your default letter-spacing here
      #{$header}, .#{$header} {
        @if map-has-key($header-defs, letter-spacing) {
          $letter-spacing-temp: rem-calc(map-get($header-defs, letter-spacing));
          letter-spacing: $letter-spacing-temp;
        } @else if map-has-key($header-defs, ls) {
          $letter-spacing-temp: rem-calc(map-get($header-defs, ls));
          letter-spacing: $letter-spacing-temp;
        } @else if $size == $-zf-zero-breakpoint {
          letter-spacing: $letter-spacing-temp;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I have added the short form `ls`.

Then use it in your `$header-styles map` :

```
$header-styles: (
  small: (
    'h1': ('fs': 24),
    'h2': ('fs': 20),
    'h3': ('fs': 19),
    'h4': ('fs': 18),
    'h5': ('fs': 17),
    'h6': ('fs': 16),
  ),
  large: (
    'h1': ('fs': 80, 'letter-spacing' : -2.4),
    'h2': ('fs': 40, 'ls' : -1),
    'h3': ('fs': 31),
    'h4': ('fs': 25),
    'h5': ('fs': 20),
    'h6': ('fs': 16),
  ),
);
```